# Create Rancher API Key with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rancher

Given access to the kubernetes cluster, but no API key, how can I programatically create a API key for rancher server?

The method [described in documentation here](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/v2.5/reference-guides/user-settings/api-keys) requires a password login an a web browser. I would like to get the same outcome programatically. Given that all the state should be on etcd, it should, in theory, be possible through kubectl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make this work:

Create a JSON file to define the token (i.e `token.json`):

```json
{
  "apiVersion": "management.cattle.io/v3",
  "authProvider": "local",
  "current": false,
  "description": <enter description>,
  "expired": false,
  "expiresAt": "",
  "isDerived": true,
  "kind": "Token",
  "metadata": {
    "labels": {
      "authn.management.cattle.io/token-userId": <enter user id>,
      "cattle.io/creator": "kubectl"
    },
    "name": <enter a token id>,
  },
  "token": <enter token>,
  "ttl": 0,
  "userId": <enter user id>,
}
```

The token ID can be any unique string to give a name of the token. For the user-id, choose a user to which this token should be long to. (see user list with `kubectl get users -n cattle-system`).

```bash
kubectl apply -f token.json
```